# HTTPS on Vibe.d

Tags: ssl, https, d, vibed

On my linode box I installed the Let's Encrypt SSL certs and created a bare-bones Vibe.d app to test my SSL connection. I always timeout. Here is the code:

```
import vibe.vibe;

void main()
{
        auto settings = new HTTPServerSettings;
        settings.port = 8080;
        settings.bindAddresses = ["::1", "127.0.0.1","50.116.15.145"];
        settings.tlsContext = createTLSContext(TLSContextKind.server);
        settings.tlsContext.useCertificateChainFile("/etc/letsencrypt/live/findyourtutor.info/cert.pem");
        settings.tlsContext.usePrivateKeyFile("/etc/letsencrypt/live/findyourtutor.info/privkey.pem");
        listenHTTP(settings, &hello);

        logInfo("Please open 'http://www.findyourtutor.info' in your browser.");
        runApplication();
}

void hello(HTTPServerRequest req, HTTPServerResponse res)
{
        res.writeBody("Hello, World!");
}
```

If I simply visit

```
www.findyourtutor.info or
findyourtutor.info
```

I can view them fine.

But if I visit `https://findyourtutor.info`, I time out.

I also time out with

```
https://findyourtutor.info:8080
https://www.findyourtutor.info
https://www.findyourtutor.info:8080
```

When logged in at linode, I can do

```
lynx https://localhost:8080
```

and lynx warns me about the certificates but I can see the site after pressing 'y' twice.

I can also do

```
lynx http://localhost
```

but not

```
lynx http://localhost:8080
```

At this point I don't know if my code is at fault or my setup is at fault.

My UFW firewall allows HTTPS from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I would use nginx as a proxy for your vibe-d app, this is better then try to use vibed with ssl.

But your setup seems really wierd. You are listening on 8080, so it should not be possible to access your site with 
`www.findyourtutor.info` or `findyourtutor.info` without specify port somehow, so I guess there is some other web server in play. You should try to listen on `443` if you want to use `https`. Or do you have allready some proxy?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Kozzi11. Yeah, it seems wierd, but somehow it works. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: Hi @Kozzi11, I found out I have multiple instance of my program after issuing ps aux, and one of them was listening at port 80! So I rebooted my linode and now everything is clearer.